# Run R RMD file with GitHub Actions

Tags: r, bash, yaml, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have two repositories that I update daily by simply opening the project in RStudio and knitting the RMD file, then pushing the results to the repo.

I would love to automate this with GitHub actions but I find the documentation highly confusing.

Is there an "Explain it like I'm 5" on doing this particular thing?

So I made a bash file located at `./bash/data_refresh.sh` and a github actions file `data_refresh.yaml`

Bash file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Rendering the page..."

Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render(input = 'README.Rmd')"

if [[ "$(git status --porcelain)" != "" ]]; then
    git config --global user.name 'my_user_name'
    git config --global user.email 'my_email_address'
    git add *
    git commit -m "Auto update Report"
    git push
fi
```

Here is my `yaml`:

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Package Data Refresh

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  schedule:
    - cron: '0  12 * * *'

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    name: refresh the dashboard
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: checkout_repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref:  'master'
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Render Rmarkdown
        run: bash ./bash/data_refresh.sh
```

I am getting the following error and not sure how to rectify it.

```
Run bash ./bash/data_refresh.sh
  bash ./bash/data_refresh.sh
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Rendering the page...
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the [workflows from `r-lib`](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/examples#render-rmarkdown) as a starting point and add your parts (rendering & cron job).

This works when triggered manually, I haven't tested the cron job:

```
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  schedule:
    - cron: '0  12 * * *'

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

name: Package Data Refresh

jobs:
  render-rmarkdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-renv@v2
      
      - name: Render Rmarkdown Readme file and Commit Results
        run: |
          echo "Rendering the page..."
          Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render(input = "README.Rmd")'
          if [[ "$(git status --porcelain)" != "" ]]; then
            git config --local user.name "$GITHUB_ACTOR"
            git config --local user.email "$GITHUB_ACTOR@users.noreply.github.com"
            git add *
            git commit -m "Auto update Report"
            git push origin
          fi
```

This uses `renv` to install the dependencies and cache the dependencies in GHA (as far as I understand). Therefore, you need to use `renv` in your repository. Simply use `renv::init()` and commit the resulting files. As you use `.Rmd`, this includes `rmarkdown`. For more information, check the [`renv` documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html).

The crucial part to make it work is that you have to use single quotes around the argument for `Rscript`, not double quotes. Otherwise it won't work.

Also, I'm quite new to GHA, so there might be other aspects you could optimise.

### Edit

Here is a version that works without `renv`, however I recommend using `renv` as it allows to cache your dependencies (packages).

```
# Workflow derived from https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/v2/examples
# Need help debugging build failures? Start at https://github.com/r-lib/actions#where-to-find-help
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  schedule:
    - cron: '0  12 * * *'

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

name: Package Data Refresh 2

jobs:
  render-rmarkdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
      
      - name: Install packages, render Rmarkdown Readme file and Commit Results
        run: |
          echo "Rendering the page..."
          Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("knitr", "rmarkdown"))'
          Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render(input = "README.Rmd")'
          if [[ "$(git status --porcelain)" != "" ]]; then
            git config --local user.name "$GITHUB_ACTOR"
            git config --local user.email "$GITHUB_ACTOR@users.noreply.github.com"
            git add *
            git commit -m "Auto update Report"
            git push origin
          fi
```

Comment: I will test it out and let you know. Thank you

Comment: Did it work or does it need some tweaks? If yes it would be great if you accept the answer

Comment: Not it did not work, I apologize for not getting back to you. Here is the error:

```bash
Run echo "Rendering the page..."
Rendering the page...
Error: Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do you use `renv` for this repository and is `rmarkdown` contained in the lockfile?

Comment: I personally do not use renv for this repo

Comment: As I've written in my answer, it depends on `renv` in order to cache the dependencies (and making your workflow run faster after the first time). However, I've also added a version without `renv`.

Comment: I’ll give it a try tomorrow

Comment: must be something else entirely going on, with and without renv, (renv like rlib says) still get failures.